# Apache2, Python3, CGI Script

Tags: apache, python-3.x, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew

**Environment:**

- Mac OS X 10.8.5
- Apache2 (version that came with the OS)
- Python2 (version that came with the OS)
- Python3 (installed via Homebrew)

This code returns "testing" in the web browser:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

from __future__ import print_function, division

print("Content-Type: text/html")  # HTML is following.
print()  # Blank line, end of headers.

print("testing")
```

But this code returns "Internal Server Error" in the web browser (using python3 this time):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

print("Content-Type: text/html")  # HTML is following.
print()  # Blank line, end of headers.

print("testing")
```

...and in the Apache2 error log:

```
env: python3: No such file or directory
Premature end of script headers: test_cgi.py
```

In `echo $PATH`:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Looking deeper, `ls -al /usr/bin/python*`:

```
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python-config
/usr/bin/python2.5 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5
/usr/bin/python2.5-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5-config
/usr/bin/python2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6
/usr/bin/python2.6-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6-config
/usr/bin/python2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin/python2.7-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
/usr/bin/pythonw
/usr/bin/pythonw2.5 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/pythonw2.5
/usr/bin/pythonw2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/pythonw2.6
/usr/bin/pythonw2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
```

And in `ls -al /usr/local/bin/python*`:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../Cellar/python3/3.3.3/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3.3 -> ../Cellar/python3/3.3.3/bin/python3.3
/usr/local/bin/python3.3-config -> ../Cellar/python3/3.3.3/bin/python3.3-config
/usr/local/bin/pythonw3.3 -> ../Cellar/python3/3.3.3/bin/pythonw3.3
```

**Questions:**

1. Since the first item in my PATH is /usr/local/bin, why can't Apache find Python3 ?
2. How can I tell Apache to use Python3 ?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same problem; I cannot figure out how to get apache to recognize python3. Furthermore, if you specify the interpreter manually:

`#!/usr/bin/python`

Works, however:

`#!/usr/local/bin/python3`

Complains about a "malformed header from script" in the apache error log...  I have no idea why this is an issue as it should just be running an arbitrary interpreter.

**EDIT**

Okay, so my problem was actually just me not outputting header information.  Your issue is that no python3 environment variable has been set.  Try changing the first line to:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Comment: problem starts when you're writing scripts on laptop but then deploy them somewhere else, you can't keep changing the shebang line everytime you want to develop, because on linux/ubuntu it's different, so i always used `/usr/bin/env python3` but then hit the same homebrew python versioning thing issue. this isn't the ultimate solution i believe ...